# HttpClient stop executing the same HttpGet method in a loop after executing twice

Tags: java, httpclient

Here is my Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    while (true) {
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html");
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
            System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After executing 2 times the HttpClient stop executing the same HttpGet. While, I instantiate a new HttpClient in the loop, it won't stop. I wander if there is something strategy preventing the HttpClient from executing the same HttpGet method more than 2 times?
  Who can help me, I will be very grateful!

Comment: Try to consume the response entity.

Comment: problem perfectly solved ! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The client is using a pool of connection to reach the web server. See [HttpClientBuilder#build()](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/9e6287c88b4479f4375970b262358ca2a25ec264/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/HttpClientBuilder.java#L736). When creating a default httpclient and nothing is specified it creates a pool with size of 2. So after 2 is used, it waits indefinitely trying to get the third connection from the pool.

You must read the response or close the connection, in order to re-use the client object.

See updated code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    while (true) {
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html");
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
            httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().close();
            System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got this. Thanks all the way! StackOverflow is a nice place for me

Comment: @Zavael, I‘m also wondering why this happens. It in deed executes 2 times.

Comment: The client is using a pool of connection to reach the web server. See HttpClientBuilder#build(). When creating a default httpclient and nothing is specified it creates a pool with size of 2. So after 2 is used, it waits indefinetly trying to get the third connection from the pool.

Comment: woo! You guy knows all! Thanks

Comment: @stalet thanks +1, that valuable comment would greatly enhance the answer :)

Comment: @Zavael: Updated the answer

Comment: @stalet is there a way to update pool size or its best practice to close the httpClient for each call.

Comment: @Jesse you should definitely close the client after each call.