# Java resilience4j Retry policy goes infinite after 2 retries

Tags: java, httpresponse, retrypolicy, resilience4j

I am using the `resilience4j` Retry policy to call the `HttpGet` request and for testing purposes,
I have set `retryOnResult` to retry when `HttpGet` request returns `200` status code.
It successfully retries when `maxAttempts` is set to `2`.

For `maxAttempts > 2` application goes in infinite state.

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpGet("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            RetryConfig retryConfig = RetryConfig.<HttpResponse>custom().waitDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                    .maxAttempts(3).retryOnResult(s -> {
                        return s.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200;
                    }).build();
            RetryRegistry registry = RetryRegistry.of(retryConfig);
            Retry retry = registry.retry("Http client");
            retry.getEventPublisher().onRetry(e -> {
                System.out.println("Retrying");
            });

            CheckedFunction0<HttpResponse> retryableSupplier = Retry.decorateCheckedSupplier(retry,
                    () -> client.execute((HttpUriRequest) request));
            response = Try.of(retryableSupplier).get();
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the root cause. Issue is not with the resiliency4j. But in above scenario same HttpGet request is called multiple times in retry scenario. And by default [httpclient creates a pool with size of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650157/httpclient-stop-executing-the-same-httpget-method-in-a-loop-after-executing-twic). So after 2 is used, it waits indefinitely trying to get the third connection from the pool.

Final Working Code :

```
public class App {
    public static int retryCounter = 0; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int maxAttempts = 4;
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpGet("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
        HttpResponse response;
        try {

            RetryConfig retryConfig = RetryConfig.<HttpResponse>custom().waitDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                    .maxAttempts(maxAttempts).retryOnResult(s -> {
                        try {
                            if (s.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

                                if (retryCounter < maxAttempts -1) {
                                    s.getEntity().getContent().close();
                                }
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e1) {
                            return true;
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            return true;
                        }

                    }).build();
            RetryRegistry registry = RetryRegistry.of(retryConfig);
            Retry retry = registry.retry("Http client");
            retry.getEventPublisher().onRetry(e -> {
                retryCounter ++;
                System.out.println("Retrying" + e.getNumberOfRetryAttempts());

            });

            CheckedFunction0<HttpResponse> retryableSupplier = Retry.decorateCheckedSupplier(retry, () -> {

                HttpResponse res = client.execute((HttpUriRequest) request);
                return res;
            });
            response = (CloseableHttpResponse) Try.of(retryableSupplier).get();
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block`enter code here`
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats not true. If the number of attempts is greater than maxAttempts, the last result is returned to the client. It's not an infinite loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response;
            RetryConfig retryConfig = RetryConfig.<String>custom().waitDuration(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                    .maxAttempts(3).retryOnResult(s -> {
                        return s.contains("Hello");
                    }).build();
            RetryRegistry registry = RetryRegistry.of(retryConfig);
            Retry retry = registry.retry("Http client");
            retry.getEventPublisher().onRetry(e -> {
                System.out.println("Retrying");
            });

            CheckedFunction0<String> retryableSupplier = Retry.decorateCheckedSupplier(retry,
                    () -> "Hello World");
            response = Try.of(retryableSupplier).get();
            System.out.println(response);

    }
```

Results in

```
Retrying
Retrying
Hello World
```

The third attempt also "failed", but the result is returned to the client.

Comment: Yes when you try calling a function which returns the 'String' it works fine. it behaves strange only with HttpResponse.